In Daniel 10:13, does "echad" mean "first" instead of "one", in that Michael is foremost of the chief princes?
Daniel 10:13 ESV

The prince of the kingdom of Persia withstood me twenty-one days, but
Michael, one of the chief princes, came to help me, for I was left
there with the kings of Persia.

Daniel 10:13 proposal

The prince of the kingdom of Persia withstood me twenty-one days, but
Michael, first of the chief princes, came to help me, for I was left there with the kings of Persia.

Ehad can mean "first" instead of "one", in being foremost or preeminent in position.
Is this translation viable?

@PerryWebb, yes, first as in preeminent.

@PerryWebb – see the quotes by commentators Gill and Henry: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/99909/90486

The Hebrew word אֶחָד (echad) as per Dan 10:13, occurs almost 1000 times in the OT.  It uses can be classified as follows:

As a cardinal number, "one", eg, Gen 1:5, 9, 21:15
As an ordinal number, "first", eg, Gen 2:11, 21
As a description of unity, eg, Gen 2:24, 11:6
"each", "every", eg, Ex 36:30, Num 7:3, 28:21
etc

My literal translation of Dan 10:13 is:

But the prince of the kingdom or Persia withstood me twenty and
one days; and behold Michael, first of the chief princes, came to help me, for I alone ...

Note that אֶחָד is used here in two senses - the first is as a cardinal number ("one") and the second as an ordinal number ("first").
This simply says that Michael is the first among the chief princes, or "chiefest" among the princes.
[I leave the controversial identity of Michael as a separate question.]

Would "foremost of the chief princes" work?

@OneGodOneLord - In this context "first" could mean either (1) chief, (2) foremost, (3) Most important, (4) Leader, etc.

Ok, thanks Dottard.

Dottard answers the question is it possible, but that isn't the question to ask for the best translation.  The question to ask is "What is probable?"

Conversely, it must be admitted that most heterodox (whether theological or exegetical) positions are built upon what is possible; but whether they are probable is a different matter. Just because a view is possible does not make it likely in a given text. -- Wallace, D. B. (1996). Greek Grammar beyond the Basics: An Exegetical Syntax of the New Testament (p. 10). Zondervan.

The phrase in question is  מִֽיכָאֵ֗ל אַחַ֛ד הַשָּׂרִ֥ים הָרִאשֹׁנִ֖ים.  The 1985 Jewish Publication Society's (JPS) translation is "Michael, a prince of the first rank."  Their previous translation (1917) is "Michael, one of the chief princes."
The more common word for first is the last word in the phrase רִאשֹׁון and related words of the lemma/root.  Sunday in Hebrew is יוֹם רִאשׁוֹן, first day [of the week]
Figure 1. The Senses of רִאשֹׁון as Used in the Tanakh (Hebrew Old Testament) (generated with Logos Bible Software)

In the Tanakh it is less common for אֶחָד to have the sense of first.
Figure 2. The Senses of אֶחָד as Used in the Tanakh (generated with Logos Bible Software)

To write "Michael, the highest rank [first] of the princes" one would expect מִֽיכָאֵ֗ל  שָּׂרִ֥ים הָרִאשֹׁון.  Adding אַחַ֛ד has the opposite effect (one of, a).

אֶחָד  ... ,


—1. numeral one ... —2. אֶ׳ one another ... —3. אֶ׳ indefinite article [a] ... —4. ordinal, first:... —5. distributive: [each]  --
Koehler, L., Baumgartner, W., Richardson, M. E. J., & Stamm, J. J. (1994–2000). In The Hebrew and Aramaic lexicon of the Old Testament (electronic ed., pp. 29–30). E.J. Brill.

This is a screen shot of the contents of -3 and -4 since this webpage cannot handle the combined English and Hebrew fonts together. The listed verses are important to see these meanings.

Checking when אֶחָד does mean first, it is almost exclusively related to time and dates.

Perry Webb – then can you explain the translation of John Gill and Matthew Henry?

I haven't found a major translation that doesn't translate אֶחָד as "one of" which makes it equivalent to the indefinite article "a" as in JPS1985. This makes me question how complete the knowledge of John Gill and Matthew Henry is of Hebrew.  This doesn't mean they aren't good commentators.  No commentary is perfect.

Michael is foremost of the chief princes, the beginning of the creation of God, the first of all creation (Rev 4:13, Col 1:15, John 1:1), and began at the beginning with God.

Then why do you ask this question? Even the New Word Translation of the Bible has "But the prince of the royal realm of Persia stood in opposition to me for 21 days. But then Miʹcha·el, one of the foremost princes, came to help me; and I remained there beside the kings of Persia." https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/daniel/10/

PerryWebb – The JWs are not right on everything, far from it. They completely failed at translating 1 Corinthians 11:15 correctly, among many other passages.

Answer
In Daniel 10:13, “echad” does not mean “first”. It means “one”.
Explanation
Perry Webb made me think and make a quick look at this word.

“But the prince of the kingdom of Persia withstood me twenty and
one (wa-echad) days” (Daniel 10:13a).

It cannot mean “twenty and first” days!
So “echad” means “one” here.

“and behold, Michael echad of the chief princes came to help me”
(Daniel 10:13b).

Including Daniel 10:13, there are 24 places where this word in the current particular form (אַחַ֛ד) is used in BibleHub. In all of them, “echad” means “one” not “first”.
I give below all of them:



Genesis 21:15: “the boy under one of the bushes” (it cannot mean first of the bushes).




Genesis 22:2: “a burnt offering on one of the mountains” (not first of the mountains).




Gen 26:10: “one of the people” (not first of the people).




Gen 32:22: “and his ten and one children” (not ten and first children).




Gen 48:22: “I give you one portion more” (not first portion more).




Leviticus 13:2: “to one of his sons”.




Numbers 16:15: “neither have I hurt one of them”.




Deuteronomy 1:2: “it is ten and one days”.




Deut 25:5: “and one of them dies”.




Judges 17:5: “consecrated one of his sons”.




1 Samuel 9:3: “Take now one of the servants”.




1 Sam 26:15: “For one of the people”.




2 Sam 6:20: “as one of the foolish ones”.




2 Sam 7:7: “a word with one of the tribes”.




2 Sam 17:22: “by dawn not even one remained”.




1 Kings 19:2: “the life of one of them”.




1 Kings 22:13: “the word of one of them”.




2 Kings 6:12: “And one of his servants said”.




2 Kings 18:24: “the face of one captain”.




1 Chronicles 17:6: “a word with any of the judges”.




Isaiah 36:9: “the face of one captain”.




Ezekiel 33:30: “one to another, everyone”.




Ezek 45:7: “comparable to one of the portions”.



And finally,



Daniel 10:13: “Michael, one of the chief”.



Under the heading of “Usage”, BibleHub gives the following description:

“Usage: The Hebrew word "echad" primarily denotes the number
one, indicating singularity or unity. It is used to express the concept of oneness, whether in numerical terms or in the sense of
unity and harmony. In the context of time, it can mean "first"
as in the first day of the month. It is also used to describe a
collective unity, as seen in the Shema (Deuteronomy 6:4), where it
emphasizes the oneness of God.”
(https://biblehub.com/hebrew/259.htm; emphasis by me)

Conclusion
Michael is “one” of the chief princes. He is not the first.
(Hebrew experts are welcome to contribute and provide more clarity)

NepheshRoi – explain why John Gill and Matthew Henry render it "foremost of chief princes"?

If you want to take John Gill as the final authority on Biblical exegesis, then you should be a Trinitarian because that one was a staunch Trinitarian and taught it!

NepheshRoi – Do you agree with him?

I agree with Scripture and how Scripture interprets Scripture.

NepheshRoi – So you think Gill & Henry were not interpreting scripture correctly?

Not in the case of Daniel 10:13.

@NepheshRou – I firmly disagree, respectfully.

Fine, we remain in peace and Christian love.


Renowned English Bible scholars John Gill and Matthew Henry note that the passage may be rendered "first of the chief princes":
John Gill:

But, lo, Michael one of the chief Princes, came to help me; called in
the New Testament an Archangel, the Prince of angels, the Head of all
principality and power; and is no other than Christ the Son of God, an
uncreated Angel; who is "one", or "the first of the chief Princes", superior to angels, in nature, name, and office; he came to
"help" Gabriel, not as a fellow creature, but as the Lord of hosts;
not as a fellow soldier, but as General of the armies in heaven and
earth, as superior to him in wisdom and strength; and he helped him by
giving him fresh counsels, orders, and instructions, which he
following succeeded.

Matthew Henry:

Here is Michael our prince, the great protector of the church, and the
patron of its just but injured cause: The first of the chief princes
(Daniel 10:13). Some understand it of a created angel, but an archangel
of the highest order (1 Thessalonians 4:16; Jude 1:9). Others think
that Michael the archangel is no other than Christ himself, the Angel
of the Covenant, and the Lord of the angels, he whom Daniel saw in
vision (Daniel 10:5). He came to help me (Daniel 10:13); and there is
none but he that holds with me in these things (Daniel 10:21).


Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

To answer your question about Daniel 10:13 and the interpretation of the term "echad", it is useful to explore several aspects of the text and the biblical context, while using biblical interpretation methods.
Background of Daniel 10:13
In this verse, we are talking about the angel Gabriel who explains to Daniel that the angel "the prince of the kingdom of Persia" resisted him for 21 days, and that he had to ask for help from Miguel (or Michael), "one of the main leaders".
Analysis of the term "echad"

Literal and lexical meaning: The Hebrew word "echad" usually means "one" as a number, but it can also be used to indicate a status of importance or elite in certain contexts. It does not necessarily designate the first in chronological order, but can refer to the one who has a high or pre-eminent position among others.
Scriptural Comparison: In the Scriptures, Michael is often associated with protection and leadership in spiritual battles (see Jude 1:9 and Revelation 12:7-8). This may indicate that he has a special or privileged position in the heavenly kingdom, reinforcing the idea that he is "the most important" among angels or spiritual leaders.
Thematic context: The Book of Daniel is filled with visions, spiritual conflicts and divine interventions. In this context, the mention of Michael as one of the main leaders underlines the importance of spiritual struggles. His mention as part of God's message to Daniel suggests that he has a crucial role in divine protection and intervention.
Historical interpretation: In the history of Jewish and Christian interpretations, Michael is strongly linked to the defense of the people of God (see Daniel 12:1), which reinforces the idea of a high stature among the angels. This could imply that his role transcends that of others, placing him in a leadership position.

